# What is a full declarator in C?

Tags: c, syntax

Harbison/Steele's C reference says that the end of a **full declarator** is a sequence point. But what is a full declarator?

> "A full declarator is a declarator that is not part of another
>   declarator"

... *what?*

So as an example, would it be guaranteed by the C standard that `int i = 0, *j = &i` stores the memory address with the value of the variable `i` in the pointer `j`?

In other words, is the `int i = 0` part a full declarator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you are mixing *declarations* and *declarators*.

Let me quote pieces of the C grammar from the standard:

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list[opt] ;

init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator

init-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator = initializer
```

And then:

```
declarator:
    pointer[opt] direct-declarator

direct-declarator:
    identifier
    ( declarator )
    ....
```

TL;DR: `int i = 0;` is a *declaration*. The `i` part is a *declarator*.

The part about full declarators is clear if you have, for example, pointers. This line:

```
int *p[3] = { 0 };
```

is a declaration. The part `*p[3]` is the *full declarator*, but `p[3]` and `p` are also (non-full) *declarators*.

And asking your first question, yes, `int i = 0, *j = &i;` is perfectly fine, because there are two full declarators: `i` and `*j`. There is a sequence point at the end of each full declarator plus another sequence point at the end of each initializer. You could even write `void *p = &p;` and it would be just fine.

Comment: In `int i = 0, *j = &i;` Is there really a sequence point in between `0,` ? Annex C says: *The following are full expressions: an initializer that is not part of a
compound literal (6.7.9);* So obviously it is. But I can't find anything relevant in 6.7.9, and Annex C is only informative. Can you point out the rule please?

Comment: @2501. The Annex C from the C standard lists all the sequence points, here you can read _"Between the evaluation of a full expression and the next full expression to be evaluated. . The following are full expressions: an initializer that is not part of a compound literal; [...]"_. Personally I find the wording a bit confusing, because what if between this full expression and  the next full expressions to be evaluated there is additional code? Where would the SP go? I would simply say "_at the end of a full expression_".

Comment: @2501: Oh, I see. Look at 6.8, paragraph 4: _"There is a sequence point between the evaluation of a full expression and the evaluation of the next full expression to be evaluated."_ And also: _"A full expression is an expression that is not part of another expression or of a declarator."_ (note that an initializer is part of the declaration but not of the declarator). And also: _"...is a full expression: an initializer that is not part of a compound literal, ..."_.

Comment: @2501: So there are one SP at the end of `i` another at the end of `*j` and one in an indeterminate point between `0` and `&i`... :-/

Comment: Just one question: Could you give me a hint why `i = i++` is problematic and `*p = &p` isn't? Why can't one assume that `i = i++` has the same effect as `i++`?

Comment: @viuser: The problem with `i = i++` is that it modifies the same l-value (`i`) twice without an intermediate SP. My sample code of `p = &p` modifies the l-value `p` just once, without even reading it.